# MongoDB replica set primary down - Java driver waits forever

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have mongodb version 3.4 replica set with 3 servers,
I want to simulate a network connection problem
My application is written in java with mongo java driver

When I pull out the ethernet cable from the primary server while in middle of 
writing operation like insert, The mongo driver waits forever for the TCP connection to be restored and my app gets stuck until I reconnect back the ethernet cable. Event tough the mongodb replica already elected new primary server

What are my options to be notified by the app, the mongodb server is down and I need to reconnect to the new primary server?

I tried to change the OS `tcp_keepalive_time` but it affects my system widely because I need very short acknowledge.

Thanks,
Sharon

More info:

Connection string:

```
mongodb://192.168.12.31:27017,192.168.12.32:27017,192.168.12.33:27017
```

I have only 3 servers, no arbiter. I have variable `MongoCollection<Document> collection`, I'm doing `find` operation that takes a long time, in the middle, when the client waits for the server response, I take out the ethernet cable from the primary mongo server. The mongo driver will wait forever. the command is:

```
collection.find(matchCriteria)
```

If I logically step down the primary, I get `MongoSocketReadException`. I Don't want to minimize the `socketTimeOut` of the driver, because I have sometimes long operations and I want to be able to get back to work as shortly as I can. If there is a new election and new primary elected when all servers connected, the current operation fails, and the next operation after the new election will succeed with the new primary. This is
`rs.conf()`:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "version" : 11,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "192.168.12.31:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {
                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "192.168.12.32:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {
                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "192.168.12.33:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {
                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 1000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 2,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 5000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : 60000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {
                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5bd6f31118b9c73f4dda22f8")
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the connection string you used to connect to the deployment? Note that you need to specify to the driver that your deployment is a replica set. See http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/ (the section titled "Connect to a replica set"). Also see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/ for a more generic explanation.

Comment: My connection string include all servers like this:
mongodb://host1:27017,host2:27017,host3:27017

If I do rs.stepDown at the primary, my app switch automatically to the new primary, I'm only having the infinity wait when the primary disconnects from the switch

Comment: Please post more details about your deployment, e.g. do you have an arbiter, what operation waits forever, on which part of the code does your app wait forever, how did you determine that the app reconnected to the new primary, the output of `rs.conf()`, and any relevant detail that might help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the replica set name in the connection string as shown in the example in the [Java driver tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/) e.g. `mongodb://192.168.12.31:27017,192.168.12.32:27017,192.168.12.33:27017/<db name>?replicaSet=<replica set name>` ?

Comment: Also, the Java driver is quite verbose in printing logs. You might want to `catch` the exception the driver throws and retry the operation. Note that the driver should automatically reconnect to the new primary, but it won't presume to know what you want to do in the face of a failure, so typically you need to tell the driver what to do in this case.